# jQuery - multiple .show and .hide not working quite right

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form with a checkbox. The checkbox, when checked, makes a table (which is inside a div) hide and is replaced with a block of text that says they checked the box.

Inside that same div, there is a select box. If the user selects anything other than '------' some of the table rows hide and are replaced with some text saying they made a selection.

However, if the user first makes a selection and then checks the checkbox, the goal is to have the div hide the whole table and be replaced with *only* one block of text - namely the text that says you've checked the box.

Convoluted, ya, but for the project it makes sense.

So here's some basic markup for clarity (some pseudo-code):

```
<checkbox input id="cBox">

<div id="myDiv">
  <table id="myTable">
    <select_box id="mySelect">
    <tr class="myTRClass">...some stuff...</tr>
    <tr class="myTRClass">...some stuff...</tr>
    <tr class="myTRClass">...some stuff...</tr>
  </table>

  <div id="replaceTable">
    ...some text telling user they checked the box
  </div>
  <div id="replaceRows" class="replaceMyRows>
    ..some text telling user they made a selection
  </div>
</div>
```

my jQuery for the select box (which should hide just the *rows* of the table). This code works:

```
t = $("#mySelect").val();
if (t == "") {
    $(".myTRClass").hide();
    $(".replaceMyRows").show();
}
else {
    $(".replaceMyRows").hide();
    $(".myTRClass").show();
}
```

Now, here's my jQuery for the check box (this should hide the whole table):

```
    t = $( '#cBox' )
    if ($(t).attr('checked')) {
        $("#myTable").hide();
        $("#replaceTable").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#replaceTable").hide();
        $("#myTable").show();
    }
```

Now here's my problem: These two sets of jQuery work fine on their own, but when I start to mix things together, I have problems.

For example: if I make a selection from the select box, the table rows hide and are replaced with my text. Perfect. But now, in this state, if I then check the check box to hide the *whole* table (which currently has some of its rows hidden) what I get is a hidden table, but *both sets of text* are present (The text saying "you made a selection" and the text that says "you checked the box").

I can't seem to get the right combo of `.show()` and `.hide()` to make this work. The result for my example should be: Hide the table, Hide the rows, Hide the *text* that says I hid the *rows*, then show the text that says I checked the checkbox.

Sorry if this is convoluted, it just seems an odd situation that should be straight forward.

Thanks for any help :)

---

Edit: Changed my title.

---

**Edit #2**

I've added a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/garfonzo/d4NfT/15/)
When it opens, the select box has '-----' chosen, so the table rows are hidden. Try selecting something else (rows show up). Try checking the box (whole table hides). However, try selecting '-----' FIRST then check the box - both texts show up. With this situation, I only want the "you checked the box" text to show up.

Ideas?

Comment: can you set up a fiddle for this?

Comment: I have added a fiddle, see Edit #2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure here but seems like you should change your markup a little bit to manage.

Here's new html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cBox">

<div id="myDiv">
  <div class="hideByChkBx">
    <select id="mySelect" />
    <table id="myTable">
      <tr class="myTRClass">...some stuff...</tr>
      <tr class="myTRClass">...some stuff...</tr>
      <tr class="myTRClass">...some stuff...</tr>
    </table>
    <div id="replaceRows" class="replaceMyRows>
      ..some text telling user they made a selection
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="replaceTable">
    ...some text telling user they checked the box
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is javascript:

```
//For select box
t = $("#mySelect").val();
if (t == "") {
    $(".myTRClass").hide();
    $(".replaceMyRows").show();
} else {
    $(".replaceMyRows").hide();
    $(".myTRClass").show();
}

//for checkbox
t = $( '#cBox' )
if ($(t).attr('checked')) {
    $(".hideByChkBx").hide();
    $("#replaceTable").show();
}
else {
    $(".hideByChkBx").show();
    $("#replaceTable").hide();
}
```

Comment: Your solution worked! Thanks. Here's my fiddle, adjusted for your suggestion, for anyone else needing the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/garfonzo/cFrDe/5/